# Sources of Krishna's mantra

Tags: scripture, krishna, mantras, identification-request

Please let me know all the sources of the below Krishna's Mantra. It looks like there are 2 or more sources of this mantra. One source that I know of is Gopala tapani Upanishad. So please provide all the other sources of the below mantra

Kleem Krishnaaya Govindaaya Gopeejana Vallabhaaya Swaha

Comment: I found it in [श्रीसुदर्शनमालामन्त्रस्तोत्रम्](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/sudarshanamAlAmantrastotram.html?lang=sa)

Comment: @Pandya no, actually it is complete Sudarshan Manta with the Mantra in question, there are sources where this mantra alone stands as a complete Mantra. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @UdayKrishna in which book this conversation is there? I think there are more than 2 sourcers

Comment: @UdayKrishna can you please find more sources, I guess there is one more and answer my questions. Thank you.

Comment: Does that Upanishad also give the other details related to the Mantra like Rishi, Chandah etc and the Nyasas? @Ram

Comment: This Mantra and some other versions of it has been dealt with in Brihat Tantrasara. Will have to check if scriptures' names are also given or not. @Ram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Brihat TantrasAra's Pariccheda 2](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm), this Mantra is also found in the Gautamiya Tantram, which is a Vaishnava Tantra.

The Rishi and other limbs of the Mantra (as found in Gautamiya) are quoted in Brihat TantrasAra's page 237.

Gautamiya states:

> TathAcha Brihad Gautamiye ----- Bhogamokshaikanilayo luptabijo
>   dashAksharah |
>  Uddharettu prithakatvena kAmavijam mahAmune ||
>   TadyogAt phalado mantro nAnyathA siddhaye bhavet ||

This verse say that during Puja or while doing the chant the Mantra must first be prefixed with the KAmaBijam (which is Kilm). Only then the Mantra can be mastered and is useful otherwise not.

The limbs of this Mantra can also be found from the following passage:

> Shirasi nArada rishaye namaha mukhe virAt chandase namaha hrudi shri
>   krishnAya devatAyai namaha | Guhye klim bijAy namaha etc...

So, NArada, VirAt and Krishna are respectively the Rishi, Chandah and DevatA of the Mantra as given in Gautamiya Tantram.

The Brihat TantrasAra also states that before doing Japa of the Mantra one is required to do 3 special NyAsas namely - Srishti NyAsa, Stithi NyAsa and Samhriti NyAsa besides doing the other regular ones.

Several related Mantras (like Klim GopijanavallabhAya SwAha etc) are also found in another Vaishnava Text called Sanatakumara Tantram as per TantrasAra.

Comment: so there are total three Scriptures-Gautamiya Tantram, Brahma Samhita and Gopal tapani Upanishad which contains this mantra correct?

Comment: I am not aware of the Upanishad as well as Brahma samhita containing the Mantra, Tantra sara and other books that i have don't talk about Brahma Samhita at all. "Klim Gopijanavallabhaya Swaha" is the basic 10-lettered Mantra for Krishna which is found in even Sanatkumar Tantram. @Ram Other similar Mantra for Krishna is "Klim Rukminivallabhaya Swaha".

Comment: @Ram I think this mantra is not there in Brahma Samhita. Can you please tell me verse number?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta This mantra is told by Goddess Saraswati to Brahma in chapter 5, sloka 24

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Welcome :)